# What is the Standard Way to Define a Norm on a Vector Space of Real-Valued Random Variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables

Let $V$ be the vector space of real-valued random variables over $\mathbb{R}$. How does one traditionally define the norm on $V$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I just split the post into two different (more focused) questions.

Comment: That space is too big, there is no sensible norm on it (AFAIK). One considers subspaces such as $L^1, L^2, L^\infty$.

Comment: Is it true that the norm for $X \in L^p$ is $E[|X|^p]$? I have seen this in some places on the web, but I am confused as to why the random variable is taken to the absolute value. Is that standard or in some cases can a norm be defined as $E[X^p]$?

Comment: What does $x^p$ mean, if $x$ is not a positive number and $p$ is not integer? And even if $p$ is integer, a norm must be a positive number, by definition. That's why one takes $|X|^p$.